# Async tasks returning no results

Tags: async-await, elixir, ecto

I have around 10-15 ecto queries which I want to run async in my API code.
I am using Task.async and Task.yeild_many

Following is the code for async task -

```
def get_tasks() do
  task_1 =
      Task.async(SomeModule, :some_function, [
          param_1,
          param_2
      ])

  task_2 =
      Task.async(SomeModule, :some_function, [
          param_1,
          param_2
      ])

  task_3 =
      Task.async(SomeModule, :some_function, [
          param_1,
          param_2
      ])

  [task_1, task_2, task_3]
end
```

I get the tasks in my main function as -

```
        [
          {_, task_1},
          {_, task_2},
          {_, task_3}
        ] =
          [
            task_1,
            task_2,
            task_3,
          ]
          |> MyCode.TaskHelper.yeild_multiple_tasks()
```

And my task helper code is given below -

```
defmodule MyCode.TaskHelper do

  def get_results_or_shutdown(tasks_with_results) do
    Enum.map(tasks_with_results, fn {task, res} ->
      res || Task.shutdown(task, :brutal_kill)
    end)
  end

  @doc """
  Returns the result of multiple tasks ran parallely

  ## Parameters
    - task_list: list, a list of all tasks
  """
  def yeild_multiple_tasks(task_list) do
    task_list
    |> Task.yield_many()
    |> get_results_or_shutdown()
  end
end
```

Each tasks are ecto queries.
The issue is the tasks are behaving randomly. Sometimes they return results, sometimes they don't. But there was no time when all the tasks have return results (for the representational purpose I have written 3 tasks,
but I have around 10-15 async tasks).
I ran the code synchronously, and it returned the correct results (obviously). I tried changing the pool_size in config to 50 for Repo, but to no avail.

Can someone please help me out with this? I am quite stuck here.

Comment: Please clarify what does mean “sometimes tasks do not return results.” At the first glance, decreasing the number of parallel executions to the number of cores and/or  increasing a timeout would probably solve it.

Comment: The tasks are behaving randomly, sometimes the result return by ecto query is 0, and sometimes it returns the expected result.
I tried increasing the timeout, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try to limit the amount of concurrently running tasks to the number of cores. Also, what do you expect to be returned instead of `0`? Maybe zero is the correct result? What kind of query is that? Please share more info about `Ecto`-related part.

Comment: Any reason that you are alternating your spelling of yeild/yield ?